# No wifi adapter found! Dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, windows-10, adapter

I dual booted Ubuntu 17.10 in my windows 10.
While working in windows wifi works fine! But in Ubuntu it is always showing
 "No wifi adapter found, 
Make sure you have a wifi adapter plugged and turned on"
Not getting any solutions online! Tried some of them but not working! Help please

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by unchecking the *Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power* option.

The otpion can be found under *Device Manager* → *Network Adapters* → *your network adapter* → *Properties* → *Power Management*. I guess it's more of a Windows problem than Ubuntu.

Comment: that did the trick for me, kinda dumb but glad it solved my issue :)

Comment: This also seemed to do it for me. Unfortunately wifi adapter was also missing from windows on random reboots so I had to keep trying until it came back.

Comment: My card does not have a Power Management tab. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Kvothe Mine is an Intel card, which had an extra property MIMO Power Saving or similar. Disabling this also fixed the problem. Just look through all settings tabs of your device and you will find something with energy.

Comment: Same issue for me, Ubuntu 16, 18, and 20 dual booting with Windows 10 and an Intel WiFi 6 AX200.  This did fix it!  Go into Device Manager and choose the device, Advanced tab (of course), MIMO Power Save Mode and set to "No SMPS".  It sometimes takes 2 boots into Ubuntu before the wireless card magically reappears.

Answer (score 6):

I had that problem in Ubuntu 17.04. Wifi worked well until I booted to windows 10. When I switched back I couldn't connect to internet via WiFI (cable connection worked though).

After few hours of following tons of solutions that I found on the internet (and dozens of restarts) I turned off my laptop, removed battery and waited 15min.

I know that this isn't any solution but in my case after turning laptop on again WiFi was back.

Comment: Sometimes Windows will power off an adapter which stays off over rebooting. If this is the case, the solution is to shutdown instead of rebooting. Upon powering on select Ubuntu from grub menu and adapter should be powered up.

Comment: That may be a reason since I don't remember to turning my laptop off instead of rebooting (until I removed battery).

Comment: Unbelievable, worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot with WIn 10. I have a desktop so I shut down, and flipped the switch on the power supply. After a few mins I turned it on and booted to linux and wifi worked again.

Comment: Shutting down fixed it for me on mint, now the real solution is to find a way to turn it back on automatically without shutting down if this situation happens.... But I don't even know where to begin

Answer (score 0):

First, check if Ubuntu lists any wireless devices or not by running:

```
iw dev | grep Interface
```

Then, Try Issuing `iwconfig` command and see If there is any wireless interface enabled or not. Then check if the wireless interface is active or not by using the `ifconfig` command.

It could look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM9Qh.jpg) or similar now

1. If your wireless interface is disabled (not showing up after `iw dev | grep interface`) you'll need to configure one.
   Head to this [link for Wireless Network Configuration in Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-configure-wireless-any-linux-desktop).
2. If your wireless interface is enabled but not showing up after `iwconfig`, maybe it's not active. In that case just find out name of the wireless interface and type :

   ```
   sudo ifconfig <interface_name> up
   ```

   In my case, my wireless interface has name `wlp6s0`, so the command for me was :

   ```
   sudo ifconfig wlp6s0 up
   ```

Answer (score 0):

i've faced this issue twice! and becuase ofthis watched hundred of videos nothing helped much but one thing noticed when i faced this issue again:-

switch to windows:-

1. Go to device manager
2. Network adpters/ or devices
3. right click on your wificard and update it

hope this will help