# Ifconfig nonexistent, no wifi adapter

Tags: wireless, adapter, ifconfig

It appears this is a common topic but I think my problem may be unique in that I cannot find ifconfig. I was trying to follow this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984303/no-wifi-adapter-found-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-17-10) and others. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. When I type

```
ifcongig
```

This is what I see.

```
Command 'ifconfig' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install net-tools
```

It sounds as though I need to do a reinstall, this time getting these default programs included so I can get wifi. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might get these default appications?

Comment: `ifconfig` is no longer bundled with Ubuntu, but you can install it with `apt` as suggested in the error output. But you can also switch to the current software, `ip`. See `man ip` to learn how to use it. Example: `ip a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later, `ifconfig` is superceded with:

```
ip addr show
```

Here is a sample output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:f7:28:ae:83:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:c5:d4:0e:64:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.xx/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 163355sec preferred_lft 163355sec
    inet6 2600:1700:5aa0:839:3463:39f0:7595:xxxx/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 595357sec preferred_lft 76778sec
    inet6 2600:1700:5aa0:839:ed1a:bd8d:e5a:xxxx/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591685sec preferred_lft 604485sec
    inet6 fe80::3f3e:a058:dc6d:df91/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here is a handy guide: https://p5r.uk/blog/2010/ifconfig-ip-comparison.html