# Wifi only works after restarting from windows

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, reboot

I'm encountering a very weird bug on my dual boot system. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Windows 10. The issue is, that whenever I directly boot onto Ubuntu, my WiFi module is recognized, but not working. However, whenever I log into Windows, hit the reboot button and then boot Ubuntu, the WiFi works perfectly fine. On Windows the WiFi works no matter what. Has anyone an idea what might be the issue here? I can't explain how this even might happen.

The WiFi module I'm using is the Intel Wifi 6 AX200 which comes with the Asus Strix 570E motherboards. Also I should mention, that in the driver tab of Software&Updates always says "Do not use this device" no matter whether the Wifi is working or not:

[image: Screenshot of Software & Updates - Additional Drivers tab]

Comment: Could this be the problem? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Wow, this did solve the problem and was a lot quicker and easier than expected.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, here's a clip from [the link](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled) @chili555 posted:

> If you have a dual-boot machine with a recent version of Windows and start seeing problems during initialization of the WiFi device when booting Linux, the problem could be due to the “fast startup” feature on Windows.
>
> With this feature enabled, Windows don't really shut down the entire system, but leaves things partially running so you can start the machine faster again. Try to disable this option, on Windows 10 it should be in “Control Panel→Hardware and Sound→Power Options→System Settings”. Select “Chooose what the power buttons do” to access the System Settings from the Power Options. Then disable the “Fast Startup” option in “Shutdown Settings”. This will cause Windows to fully shutdown and may solve the issue.

Also relevant:

- [No wifi adapter found! Dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984303/no-wifi-adapter-found-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-17-10)

> I had the same problem. I resolved it by unchecking the Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power option.

> The option can be found under `Device Manager → Network Adapters → your network adapter → Properties → Power Management`. I guess it's more of a Windows problem than Ubuntu.

Comment: This is not an answer it is a re posting of someone else answer.

Comment: I've posted it because it is the answer, but it was posted as a comment 2-3 years ago, and I've quoted the relevant part in case the link in the comment becomes dead at some point.