# Ubuntu 22.04 While establishing connection for Ethernet, Wi-Fi drops for other devices such as phones, tablets and laptops

Tags: boot, networking, wireless, ethernet, router

I am using **Wired (Ethernet)** connection on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installed on ZFS root.Just to be clear, my Network card doesn't supports wireless connection at all.
When I am booting my Ubuntu or trying to shutdown by using command 'sudo shutdown now' or by using shutdown button from integrated interface (in my case KDE Plasma) - other devices such as tablets, phones, laptops immediately disconnects from my Wi-Fi network and cannot reconnect until Ethernet is being established on my machine.

(If I try `sudo shutdown --poweroff now` Wi-Fi doesn't drops for other devices)

And that's really weird, because I've tried everything to solve this problem, absolutely everything, I've reinstalled system 5 times and now I am here, asking this question.

First I want to explain one thing, **for system installation with ZFS filesystem** I've followed **instructions from official [openZFS docs.](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html)** And everything should be fine right? Well actually no, I've noticed after reinstalling systems that for some reason **everything is fine until you ran command** `apt dist-upgrade` after this problem will occur...

Well okay, so if the problem occurs after processing `apt dist-upgrade` **then the problem occurs because of upgrading some packages**? I tried **to list and downgrade all packages** that has been upgraded after processing this command, and **still the same problem.**

Solutions that I've tried when was troubleshooting:

- [22.04, wifi keeps disconnecting for a few seconds frequently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403773/22-04-wifi-keeps-disconnecting-for-a-few-seconds-frequently) | powersave is disabled in NetworkManager.
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2452472 | in bios power management - settings "control WWAN radio" and "control WLAN radio" are disabled.
- [Wifi stops working after reboot unless I boot Windows first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345733/wifi-stops-working-after-reboot-unless-i-boot-windows-first) | I don't have dual boot, but anyways I've checked that Fast Boot, Secure Boot (CSM) are disabled.

First time I thought this is the problem with DHCP4, I tried to change in my network service using from internal DHCP to dhcpclient and still the same result. Then I've tried to set Static IP instead of dynamic from DHCP, and still the same result.

I've also thought that maybe the problem is with NetworkManager, but even after moving to networkd problem is still there.

I've also noticed this message in journalctl, **my internet is 100mbps not 1gbps** maybe this is the issue? :

```bash
Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-200:00: Downshift occurred from negotiated speed 1Gbps to actual speed 100Mbps, check cabling!
8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full (downshifted) - flow control rx
```

I've tried to fix it by turning off auto negotiation in rc.local and it didn't help.

I've also noticed these strange messages from avahi-daemon when network service trying to establish my Ethernet connection:

```
Jul 10 00:25:31 localhost avahi-daemon[1024]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::c23f:d5ff:feaf:>
Jul 10 00:25:31 localhost avahi-daemon[1024]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv6 with address 2001:12:34:45:1:2:3:6.
Jul 10 00:25:31 localhost avahi-daemon[1024]: Registering new address record for 2001:12:34:45:1:2:3:6 on enp2s0.*.
Jul 10 00:25:31 localhost avahi-daemon[1024]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::c23f:d5ff:feaf:6ebd on enp2s0.
```

I've tried to fix it by just **turning off avahi-daemon because I didn't want to use*

After unsuccessful attempts to fix this problem, I wanted to see difference in journactl between second boot (because First boot was system configuration) and latest boot with this problem. So here is:

**Second boot:**
https://pastebin.com/EpaByGpY

**Latest boot** (**with issue**, and with enabled debug logging for networkd):
https://pastebin.com/jWkzEb2E

And that's really interesting because in the **latest boot log there is messages:**

```
Jul 13 01:41:40 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=25 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:41:40 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=26 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:41:40 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Forgetting route: dst: 192.168.1.0/24, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.217, scope: link, table: main(254), proto: kernel, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:41:40 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Forgetting route: dst: 192.168.1.255/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.217, scope: link, table: local(255), proto: kernel, type: broadcast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:41:40 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Forgetting route: dst: 192.168.1.217/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.217, scope: host, table: local(255), proto: kernel, type: local, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:41:40 elias-ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[998]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
Jul 13 01:41:41 elias-ubuntu PackageKit[1930]: get-updates transaction /733_aadebadb from uid 1000 finished with success after 519ms
Jul 13 01:41:42 elias-ubuntu dbus-daemon[1551]: [session uid=1000 pid=1551] Activating service name='org.kde.KSplash' requested by ':1.24' (uid=1000 pid=1820 comm="/usr/bin/plasmashell ")
Jul 13 01:41:43 elias-ubuntu dbus-daemon[1551]: [session uid=1000 pid=1551] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications'
Jul 13 01:41:51 elias-ubuntu systemd[1541]: Started Konsole - Terminal.
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Flags change: +LOWER_UP +RUNNING
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu kernel: r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=27 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: LLDP: Started LLDP client
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Started LLDP.
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Gained carrier
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Requesting address: 192.168.1.217/24 (valid forever, preferred forever), flags: n/a
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Setting addresses
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: State changed: configured -> configuring
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=28 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Requesting route: dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 192.168.1.1, prefsrc: n/a, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: static, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Requesting routes
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=29 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Configuring address: 192.168.1.217/24 (valid forever, preferred forever), flags: n/a
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Remembering updated address: 192.168.1.217/24 (valid forever, preferred forever), flags: permanent
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=30 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=31 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Remembering foreign route: dst: 192.168.1.217/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.217, scope: host, table: local(255), proto: kernel, type: local, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Remembering foreign route: dst: 192.168.1.255/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.217, scope: link, table: local(255), proto: kernel, type: broadcast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Remembering foreign route: dst: 192.168.1.0/24, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.217, scope: link, table: main(254), proto: kernel, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Configuring route: dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 192.168.1.1, prefsrc: n/a, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: static, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Addresses set
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static routes are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Received remembered route: dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 192.168.1.1, prefsrc: n/a, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: static, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Routes set
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: State changed: configuring -> configured
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=32 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[998]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Jul 13 01:42:15 elias-ubuntu PackageKit[1930]: get-updates transaction /734_eeeabecd from uid 1000 finished with success after 502ms
Jul 13 01:42:18 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 13 01:42:25 elias-ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[998]: Timed out waiting for reply from 185.125.190.56:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jul 13 01:42:28 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu kernel: r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Flags change: -LOWER_UP -RUNNING
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=33 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Lost carrier
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: LLDP: Stopping LLDP client
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Removing route: dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 192.168.1.1, prefsrc: n/a, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: static, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Removing address: 192.168.1.217/24 (valid forever, preferred forever), flags: permanent
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: State is configured, dropping foreign config
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=34 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Forgetting route: dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 192.168.1.1, prefsrc: n/a, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: static, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Forgetting address: 192.168.1.217/24 (valid forever, preferred forever), flags: permanent
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=35 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=36 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Forgetting route: dst: 192.168.1.0/24, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.217, scope: link, table: main(254), proto: kernel, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Forgetting route: dst: 192.168.1.255/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.217, scope: link, table: local(255), proto: kernel, type: broadcast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Forgetting route: dst: 192.168.1.217/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.217, scope: host, table: local(255), proto: kernel, type: local, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:33 elias-ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[998]: No network connectivity, watching for changes.
Jul 13 01:42:34 elias-ubuntu PackageKit[1930]: get-updates transaction /735_ddbbaddc from uid 1000 finished with success after 508ms
Jul 13 01:42:34 elias-ubuntu systemd[1541]: Starting Save current user state periodically...
Jul 13 01:42:34 elias-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting ZSYS daemon service...
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu org.kde.KSplash[2012]: org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu dbus-daemon[1551]: [session uid=1000 pid=1551] Activated service 'org.kde.KSplash' failed: Process org.kde.KSplash exited with status 1
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd[1]: Started ZSYS daemon service.
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu zsysctl[2055]: Successfully saved as "autozsys_9tocyd"
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd[1541]: Finished Save current user state periodically.
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu kernel: r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control off
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Flags change: +LOWER_UP +RUNNING
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=37 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: LLDP: Started LLDP client
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Started LLDP.
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Gained carrier
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Requesting address: 192.168.1.217/24 (valid forever, preferred forever), flags: n/a
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Setting addresses
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: State changed: configured -> configuring
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=38 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Requesting route: dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 192.168.1.1, prefsrc: n/a, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: static, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Requesting routes
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=39 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Configuring address: 192.168.1.217/24 (valid forever, preferred forever), flags: n/a
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Remembering updated address: 192.168.1.217/24 (valid forever, preferred forever), flags: permanent
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=40 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static addresses are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=41 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Remembering foreign route: dst: 192.168.1.217/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.217, scope: host, table: local(255), proto: kernel, type: local, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Remembering foreign route: dst: 192.168.1.255/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.217, scope: link, table: local(255), proto: kernel, type: broadcast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Remembering foreign route: dst: 192.168.1.0/24, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.217, scope: link, table: main(254), proto: kernel, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Configuring route: dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 192.168.1.1, prefsrc: n/a, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: static, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Addresses set
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: link_check_ready(): static routes are not configured.
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Received remembered route: dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 192.168.1.1, prefsrc: n/a, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: static, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: Routes set
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: enp2s0: State changed: configuring -> configured
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=42 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Jul 13 01:42:43 elias-ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[998]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Jul 13 01:42:44 elias-ubuntu PackageKit[1930]: get-updates transaction /736_deebeede from uid 1000 finished with success after 501ms
Jul 13 01:42:45 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 13 01:42:45 elias-ubuntu systemd-networkd[1339]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Jul 13 01:42:53 elias-ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[998]: Timed out waiting for reply from 185.125.190.58:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jul 13 01:42:54 elias-ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[998]: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

Thats really weird. Not just because I've already disabled LLDP client but for some reason it still enabled, and also because networkd for some reason 3 times forgets routes and ip addressess then retries to remember them, why networkd doing so? This also happens for NetworkManager.

Also I've noticed that in etc/systemd/network/ there is no .network files, maybe this is the issue? **Should I create .network file by myself?** Isnt systemd-network-generator.service should generate .network file?

Then I found this post: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2024327
and this on askubuntu.com: [wifi issues in ubuntu 22.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403954/wifi-issues-in-ubuntu-22-04lts)
and other posts about Wi-Fi problems where the only one solution was just to install another version of kernel: [How Do I update my kernel to the latest one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388115/how-do-i-update-my-kernel-to-the-latest-one/1388117#1388117) [22.04, wifi keeps disconnecting for a few seconds frequently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403773/22-04-wifi-keeps-disconnecting-for-a-few-seconds-frequently)
So I thought that **the problem is with my kernel**, I've tried different versions of mainline kernels, this is the list:

- 5.18 (getting the same issue)
- 5.17.5 (getting the same issue)
- 5.16 (getting the same issue)
- 5.15.20 (getting the same issue)
- 5.15.0-76 (already was installed, getting the same issue)

If I try **to boot from Ubuntu 22.04 LiveCD** there is **no problem with Wi-Fi connection**, Wi-Fi doesn't turns off at boot, everything is fine.

If I try **to fresh install from Ubuntu 22.04 LiveCD** there is will be **no problem with Wi-Fi connection**, so maybe you guys thinking - **this is the solution just reinstall the system** from default installer **but isn't following the documentation from openzfs by using default installer is the same with installing system through default installer.**

I've also noticed that **Ubuntu 22.04 LiveCD uses Kernel version 5.19,** so now I am thinking about installing kernel 5.19, I've heard that **kernel 5.19 was released with new Major Networking Tweaks**, **so maybe there is a fix for my problem that I have?** The most painful thing is that **I might upgrade my zfs Filesystem version** and how I can do this, **this is another question**, because there is no documentations or tutorials about this.
*(I have zfs version 2.1.5, which doesn't supports kernel 5.19 and higher)*

I am tired from this, I've actually tried everything, any answer will be appreciated.

**My netplan conf /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml:**

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      accept-ra: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.217/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      #routes:
      #  - to: default
      #    via: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [127.0.0.53,8.8.8.8,8.8.8.4]
```

**My ip addr show:** (dont think about fbi0, this interface is from wondershaper service that I've installed, just to be clear, I've encountered this problem BEFORE installing wondershaper service)

```bash
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:3f:d5:af:6e:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.217/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c23f:d5ff:feaf:6ebd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ifb0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc htb state UNKNOWN group default qlen 32
    link/ether 76:be:2b:97:8d:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**My ip route show:**

```bash
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0 proto static 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.217
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```bash
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 0c
       serial: c0:3f:d5:af:6e:bd
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.20-051520-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.1.217 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

there is no output for:
**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3**
and for:
**rfkill list**

so there is output for **lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3**

```bash
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
        Subsystem: Elitegroup Computer Systems RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1019:8116]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

Any answer will be appreciated.
If you guys need another useful information, please tell me about this in comments and I will edit my question later.

Comment: Please update question with output of `sudo lshw -C network` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` and `rfkill list`.

Comment: @mpboden updated right now. My network card doesn't supports wireless connection at all, so there is output for "lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3"

Comment: I’m confused. If your network card doesn’t support wireless, then how do you expect wireless? Yet you state, “my Wi-Fi turns off on all devices”. I think I’m misunderstanding the problem. I see one network device with a driver and an IP address. I see nothing regarding a Wi-Fi device or configuration.

Comment: @mpboden I meant that when my system booting, other devices such as phones, tablets disconnects from Wi-Fi and can't reconnect again until Ethernet connection is being established on my machine. I am not sure this is fine, because when I've tried to fresh install from standard Ubuntu 22.04 LiveCD, everything was fine, but when I've tried to follow instructions from openzfs to install Ubuntu on ZFS root, I've encountered this problem. The most interesting thing is that this problem occurs only after "apt dist-upgrade" but even after downgrading all packages after this didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of your network seems quite broken.

We see that your other network devices *need your Ubuntu computer* in order to get an internet connection (even though there's no reason for that). **You should inspect the configuration of those devices.** (I would recommend using the laptop, as it's probably easier to gather info from that one)

See which IP addresses they get assigned, their gateway, their dns servers, what a traceroute shows...

My suspicion is that your computer is acting as dhcp server, probably posing itself as the gateway,  and redirecting the traffic to the router. That would explain the other devices losing their internet when the computer is down.

As for the error not appearing until `apt dist-upgrade`, that must be updating some dhcp package, which either ends up configuring itself in that broken way, or just reloads to apply the existing configuration on such manner.