# Can't load WiFi adapter (Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak])

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

My WiFi adapter stopped discovering networks today. After a reboot the adapter is not even loaded.

---

Running Ubuntu 18.04

Secure boot is disabled.

- `dmesg | grep iwl`

  ```
  [ 6.154661] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002) 
  [ 6.249463] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -110
  ```
- `lshw -c network`

  ```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:604411c000-604411ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 90:20:3a:1b:d8:1d
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:58200000-58200fff memory:6042200000-6042203fff
  ```
- `lspci -v`

  ```
  00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0034
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at 604411c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] #00
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [164] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0010 Rev=0 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
  ```
- `rfkill list`
- `modprobe iwlwifi`
- `iwconfig`

  ```
  enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

  lo        no wireless extensions.
  ```
- `dmesg | grep -i firmware`

  ```
  [    0.211684] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
  [    1.242245] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
  [    6.219664] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
  ```

---

I tried to re-install `iwlwifi` as per [Unable to get wifi adapter working - clean 19.04 install - network unclaimed](https://askubuntu.com/a/1156246/1039539), but the error persists:

- `dmesg | grep iwl`

  ```
  [    6.015501] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
  [    6.015502] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8613:3ae69204
  [    6.085935] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
  [    6.179958] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -110
  ```
- `lsmod | grep iwl`

  ```
  iwlwifi               385024  0
  cfg80211              704512  1 iwlwifi
  compat                 16384  2 iwlwifi,cfg80211
  ```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error for the longest time, upgrading the kernel has fixed it for me.
Run this to upgrade the kernel intelligently with all the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Update my problem was actually because of dual boot because of windows power management https://askubuntu.com/questions/984303/no-wifi-adapter-found-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-17-10 this solved it for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. After wasting a lot of time with other solutions, yours solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem persists with Intel Wireless-AC 9560. Till now, there is no solution for this.
I have tried everything from switching to older kernel to updating the drivers.
There can be some work arounds:

1. Use external WiFi adapter.
2. Use USB Tethering from your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by the command:
`sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

Then restart system.

It should work, because it reinstalls Intel adapter stuff.