# Wi-Fi & Touchpad ASUS TUF F15 FX506HM

Tags: networking, drivers, asus

I am very new to Linux and Ubuntu. I have been a Windows user all my life, and now, I want to switch to Linux as I hope to become a better programmer. I just got a job as a placement software developer and got a brand new laptop, ASUS TUF F15 FX506HM, and I installed Ubuntu from a flash drive. Unfortunately, I can't seem to make my Wi-Fi connection work. Whenever I am entering the Wi-Fi settings I can see that an adapter is not found. I tried multiple tutorials and forums before asking this question here, but what can I do to make my Wi-Fi work?

By running a couple commands found on different tutorials I came to the conclusion that my wireless interface is not recognized for some reason. I tried checking the bios, but there was not luck. Below are the commands run and the output.

```
teodor-avram@Nabu:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2d:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f iomemory:620-61f iomemory:620-61f memory:622c100000-622c1fffff memory:622c200000-622c203fff memory:622c204000-622c204fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2e:00.0
       logical name: enp46s0
       version: 15
       serial: fc:34:97:95:cb:d6
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-55-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.100.52 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:86204000-86204fff memory:86200000-86203fff
```

```
teodor-avram@Nabu:~$ lspci
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a36 (rev 05)
0000:00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a01 (rev 05)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a60 (rev 01)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a03 (rev 05)
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a2b (rev 05)
0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 9a11 (rev 05)
0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a17 (rev 05)
0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a1f (rev 05)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 43ed (rev 11)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 43ef (rev 11)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 43e8 (rev 11)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 43e0 (rev 11)
0000:00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43bf (rev 11)
0000:00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 43b6 (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 438b (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 43c8 (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 43a3 (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 43a4 (rev 11)
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2520 (rev a1)
0000:01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228e (rev a1)
0000:2d:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961
0000:2e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a0f (rev 05)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 174a
```

I know that Linux requires skill, that I do not have yet. Also, my touch pad is not working, do not know why... Could you please help and guide me with the wireless interface problem? Also, a guide to surely install all drivers needed and updates would come in handy. Thank you very much for your time and help, it is very much appreciated!

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340800/wifi-not-working-on-asus-rog-zephyrus-g14-2021/1344040#1344040

Comment: The issue persist, neither the touchpad nor the wifi is working...

Comment: Please show us: `uname -r`

Comment: teodor-avram@quillian:~/Desktop$ uname -r
5.11.0-18-generic

Comment: rn it 5.11, but I have tried every possible kernel version

Comment: tired the insecure boot as well, did not work either

Comment: The link I gave says, in part: "Then updated kernel to 5.12 and Wi-Fi is working now!" Did you also try that?

Comment: Yes sir, I have, I will do it again right now, but I am very sure it does not work...

Comment: Also, now I am trying to install older versions of Ubuntu to see if it works on them. Considering 20.04 and 21.04 did not work

Comment: I also have the same device. Having the same issue as well. Updating the kernel resolved WiFi issue. Are you facing any issues with `Bluetooth` ? I guess there is an issue with Bluetooth also. Even after switching it on, the Bluetooth section (settings) says `Bluetooth turned off`. Because of this can't even connect a Bluetooth mouse. Did you find any ways to fix the issues?

Comment: @AKA Please start your own new question.

Comment: @chili555 That would lead to a duplicate question. The issues are same.

Comment: This question is about how to get the wireless going. Your new question will ideally be about how to get the *bluetooth* working @AKA

Answer (score 2):

====== Wi-Fi SOLVED ======

The link chili555 gave was very useful. If the solution in the link provided by him does not work from the first try, completely remove ubuntu and any other data from your computer and install again 21.04, it works even with 20.04. I do not know why it did not work the first time I tried, but reinstalling was not the solution. I had to completely erase the disk, and then install again. Although it did not solve the touch pad problem. Thank you very much chili555! You were really helpful.

Comment: I also have the same device. Having the same issue as well. Are you facing any issues with `Bluetooth` ? I guess there is an issue with Bluetooth also. Even after switching it on, the Bluetooth section (settings) says `Bluetooth turned off`. Because of this can't even connect a Bluetooth mouse. Did you find any ways to fix the issues?

Comment: Same issues (touchpad and bluetooth) for me as well. Were you able to get touchpad working?

Comment: I also have issues with my touchpad, but the solution above solved my problems regarding Bluetooth and Wi-Fi.

Answer (score -1):

Today, all of a sudden, the touchpad started to work for me under Arch Linux. Try updating your system.

Libinput identifies the touchpad as:

```
Device:           ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event258
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             101x52mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```

And XInput identifies it as:

```
⎜   ↳ ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Mouse               id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1203:00 04F3:307A Touchpad            id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Info about the kernel:

```
$ uname -r
5.13.12-arch1-1
```