# Wi-Fi not working in fresh Ubuntu install version 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, acer, mediatek

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a new laptop(Acer Aspire 7 R5 5500U, GTX 1650)

Installation was successful but it failed to detect Wi-Fi :(

Disabled secure-boot, no good

Output of  `sudo lshw -C network` :

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: 08:8f:c3:17:5b:47
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d1504000-d1504fff memory:d1500000-d1503fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:fcd2000000-fcd20fffff memory:fcd2100000-fcd2103fff memory:fcd2104000-fcd2104fff
```

Output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list` :

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7961]
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
6: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

askubuntu recommended I run a script for all-in-one info for wireless(script provided at : https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/44179).

I've uploaded the txt on google drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tm1CrgdgdqDoZ57D9RtALv-pDCc8l-8r/view?usp=sharing

All help will be appreciated, thanks in advance :D

Comment: perhaps update the kernel as described here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340800/wifi-not-working-on-asus-rog-zephyrus-g14-2021

Comment: @AlexOnLinux thank you so much, that solved the issue :D

Sorry for not replying earlier, I was exhausted and went to sleep not long after I posted this last night.